# Razor if-statement for AJAX requests

Tags: c#, ajax, json, entity-framework, razor

Currently, my provider is providing the logic to my controller. My controller then passes this data into my JSON. I am trying to access this data without an AJAX request if a certain case happens (0) and else (1) make an AJAX request. My logic works as when I test out the the code, I check my JSON in a view and it works accordingly. My only trouble is getting the if statement to work in my current view.

My provider: Where Status is a dictionary

```
            if (Status["CheckIfCsIsRunning"] == 0 && Status["CheckIfGhIsRunning"] == 0)
            {
                int ButtonStatus = 0;
                Status.Add("ButtonStatus", ButtonStatus);            // 0 --> do not display
            }
            else
            {
                int ButtonStatus = 1;
                Status.Add("ButtonStatus", ButtonStatus);            // 1 --> display
            }

            return Status;
```

My controller:

```
 public class GhCsStatusController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.CheckIfCsIsRunning = GhCsStatusProvider.GetGhCsStatus()["CheckIfCsIsRunning"];
        ViewBag.CheckIfGhIsRunning = GhCsStatusProvider.GetGhCsStatus()["CheckIfGhIsRunning"];
        ViewBag.CsStatus = GhCsStatusProvider.GetGhCsStatus()["CsStatus"];
        ViewBag.GhStatus = GhCsStatusProvider.GetGhCsStatus()["GhStatus"];
        ViewBag.ButtonStatus = GhCsStatusProvider.GetGhCsStatus()["ButtonStatus"];

        return View();
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
    ...
    ...
    "ButtonValue": @ViewBag.ButtonStatus
}
```

view:

```
@if(@ViewBag.ButtonStatus == 0){
    // do something
    // no AJAX request
}
else {
    // AJAX request
}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Comment: Well the logic of my view is to grab some data (AJAX) and create buttons according to this data OR not create buttons according to the data in the cntroller

Comment: Again you are not describing your issue.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan the whole view is not working. When my data says don't create values, itstill does..